# Submit form & open _blank window

Tags: forms, submit

I've seen examples of a form being submitted and a new window being opened via `_blank`. However, I can't seem to reproduce the results. See my code, below.

In the `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    function submitForm(formId) {
        newDialog = window.open('http://redhue.ir/upload/upload.php', '_form','status=no,scrollbars=no');
        document.forms[formId].target='_form';
        document.forms[formId].submit();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

In the `<body>` tag:

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return submitForm(this)">
```

But it just opens the new window and goes to `test.php`, but the form doesn't work, and there is no `POST` action, which means that `test.php` does not receive any form input.

What am I doing wrong, and how can this issue be resolved?